# Rails 4: testing GET request on a namespaced controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a failing test that I'm struggling to understand. I have a controller `class Users::QueriesController < ApplicationController` at app/controllers/users/queries_controller.rb which has a `show` action, and a corresponding namespaced route:

```
namespace :users do
  resources :queries
end
```

I also have a test at test/controllers/users/queries_controller_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class Users::QueriesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "accessing :show action" do
    get :show
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

Running this test results in `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:controller=>"users/queries", :action=>"show"}`.

Running `rake routes` includes this line: `users_query GET    /users/queries/:id(.:format)      users/queries#show`.

What's going wrong here? I'm using Rails 4.0.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to provide an id to the show action

```
  test "accessing :show action" do
    get :show, {:id => 1}
    assert_response :success
  end
```

That's the right way prior to rails 4.

Please have a try, and let me know the outcome.

Comment: Ah! Such a simple mistake. Guess is was one of those days. Thanks!